# jQuery objects are internally converted to JavaScript arrays, how do I copy that behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes a jQuery object show up as an array in Chrome's Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261670/what-makes-a-jquery-object-show-up-as-an-array-in-chromes-developer-tools)

I am writing a very small, jQuery-like, DOM wrapper in JavaScript, containing only the (few) functions I need most. I have noticed that, when I log a jQuery object to the console of my browser, the object is actually an array. For example: [Document]. I would like to copy that behavior. Can anyone explain me how jQuery does this internally, or even better point me to some relevant lines in the jQuery source code?
I know that objects and arrays in JavaScript have much in common, but jQuery seems to return true arrays for the $ selections, not objects.
I have already read the following post on stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to answer my question:

[Are javascript Arrays actually implemented as arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233814/are-javascript-arrays-actually-implemented-as-arrays)

Comment: Thank you both, both links contain the answer (somewhere). I had already followed Sergey's suggestion below and noticed that the presence of the length and splice prototype members makes the difference for Chrome (and apparently also for Firefox). Therefore I have marked that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is in the presence of:

- length
- splice

prototyped object members. Development consoles print objects that implement these two members as if they were arrays.

```
var myArray = function() {};
myArray.prototype.length = 0;
myArray.prototype.splice = function(){};

console.log(new myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery object is just an ordinary JavaScript function object with a `length` property and properties with numeric names, plus other methods borrowed from `Array.prototype` (as well as many jQuery-specific methods). It does not inherit from `Array.prototype`. You can see this near the start of jQuery's uncompressed source (taken from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js):

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

Browser consoles check objects for being Array-like by checking for the presence of Array properties. Firebug, for example, checks for a `length` property and a `splice()` method, both of which a jQuery object has. You can see the `splice()` method further down in the source, probably only added to persuade browser consoles to display jQuery objects as arrays:

```
// For internal use only.
// Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
push: push,
sort: [].sort,
splice: [].splice
```

Comment: Having a length property is insufficient. See the answers to the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Quentin Insufficient for appearing as an array in the console, yes. I hadn't really tried to address that, but I'll update.

Comment: Having numeric named properties is also insufficient.

Comment: @Quentin: I know. That bit was in there before the recent update. As I said, initially I wasn't really trying to address the issue of it looking like an array in the console; I was rather trying to give an overview of why it looks array-like. Perhaps I shouldn't have bothered, given that there are duplicate questions with reasonably sensible answers.