# Remove multiple elements from array in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays. The first array contains some values while the second array contains indices of the values which should be removed from the first array. For example:

```
var valuesArr = new Array("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5");   
var removeValFromIndex = new Array(0,2,4);
```

I want to remove the values present at indices `0,2,4` from `valuesArr`. I thought the native `splice` method might help so I came up with:

```
$.each(removeValFromIndex,function(index,value){
    valuesArr.splice(value,1);
});
```

But it didn't work because after each `splice`, the indices of the values in `valuesArr` were different. I could solve this problem by using a temporary array and copying all values to the second array, but I was wondering if there are any native methods to which we can pass multiple indices at which to remove values from an array.

I would prefer a jQuery solution. (Not sure if I can use `grep` here)

Answer (score 343, accepted):

There's always the plain old `for` loop:

```
var valuesArr = ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"],
    removeValFromIndex = [0,2,4];    

for (var i = removeValFromIndex.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
   valuesArr.splice(removeValFromIndex[i],1);
```

Go through `removeValFromIndex` in reverse order and you can `.splice()` without messing up the indexes of the yet-to-be-removed items.

Note in the above I've used the array-literal syntax with square brackets to declare the two arrays. This is the recommended syntax because `new Array()` use is potentially confusing given that it responds differently depending on how many parameters you pass in.

**EDIT**: Just saw your comment on another answer about the array of indexes not necessarily being in any particular order. If that's the case just sort it into descending order before you start:

```
removeValFromIndex.sort(function(a,b){ return b - a; });
```

And follow that with whatever looping / `$.each()` / etc. method you like.

Comment: wont slicing mess up the index

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - No, not if you do it correctly, which is what my answer explains.

Comment: so forEach it'd be this ..`var bigarr = [3,4,6,7,8,2,4,7,9]
var rmv = [1,5];
rmv.forEach(function(e,i){bigarr.splice(rmv[rmv.length-i-1],1);});`

Comment: `function del(x,y){y.forEach(function(e,i){x.splice(y[y.length-i-1],1);});}`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - I guess that would work, but I wouldn't use a _forEach_ unless I intended to use the _e_ parameter, so I'd sort the array in descending order and then use the _forEach_ without doing arithmetic on _i_ - note that the OP said that the values in the index array might start out of order so they'd have to be sorted anyway...

Comment: +1, I didn't realized I had to do the splice in reverse order, although instead of using forEach, my approach is using `$.each(rvm.reverse(), function(e, i ) {})`

Comment: this will only work if `removeValFromIndex ` is in sorted in ascending order

Comment: @KunalBurangi - the answer explicitly covers sorting.

Comment: removeValFromIndex sorting should be ascending, not descending.[0, 2 ,4] like at the original answer, but the NOTE says "descending" that's wrong

Comment: @ElRey777 - My edit note says *descending* order because it also says to follow that with `$.each()`. That is, sort descending if using a "conventional" ascending index loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok thanks for the clarification seems I got this EDIT part wrong

Comment: I would like to draw attention to how inefficient this repeated-splicing method is, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824017/93910 . In short, there's a simple algorithm where you don't need to shift all the later items each time you remove one!

Answer (score 55):

I suggest you use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var valuesArr = ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"];
var removeValFrom = [0, 2, 4];
valuesArr = valuesArr.filter(function(value, index) {
     return removeValFrom.indexOf(index) == -1;
})
```

Comment: indexOf inside of filter... not optimum

Comment: upvote. faster than the splice method according to https://jsperf.com/remove-multiple/1

Comment: Yes it's faster than splice but will create a new array, not delete items in place.

Answer (score 37):

Here is one that I use when not going with lodash/underscore:

```
while(IndexesToBeRemoved.length) {
    elements.splice(IndexesToBeRemoved.pop(), 1);
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution! At first I thought this wouldn't work because I thought that every time you call `slice` you would have to recalculate the indexes to be removed (-1 on `IndexestoBeRemoved`), but it actually works!

Comment: Too much clever

Comment: This solution is worked if only `IndexesToBeRemoved` array is sorted by ascending.

Comment: Those indices will be invalidated after the first splice.

Comment: @shinzou - Not if `IndexesToBeRemoved` is sorted (ascending).

Comment: Rebuilding the array each time is presumably `O(array.length)`, and you're doing that `indices.length` times (with `array.length` decreasing linearly), so this solution is probably about `O(array.length*indices.length)` in computational cost (or `O(array.length*indices.length/(1+indices.length/array.length))` exactly, I think). Surely there has to be a way to go through `array` only once.

Answer (score 18):

Not `in-place` but can be done using `grep` and `inArray` functions of `jQuery`.

```
var arr = $.grep(valuesArr, function(n, i) {
    return $.inArray(i, removeValFromIndex) ==-1;
});

alert(arr);//arr contains V2, V4
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/gDcFu/6/) fiddle.

Comment: It would be (close enough to) in-place if you just said `valuesArr = $.grep(...);`

Comment: @nnnnnn ha ha ha I was leaving for a meeting (you know they make you so productive) so did not experiment much.

Comment: @cept0 Why the downvote? OP asked for a jQuery solution.

Comment: jsfiddler - Error 404. We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Answer (score 18):

A simple and efficient (linear complexity) solution using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const valuesArr = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'];   
const removeValFromIndex = [0, 2, 4];

const indexSet = new Set(removeValFromIndex);

const arrayWithValuesRemoved = valuesArr.filter((value, i) => !indexSet.has(i));

console.log(arrayWithValuesRemoved);
```

The great advantage of that implementation is that the Set lookup operation (`has` function) takes a constant time, being faster than nevace's answer, for example.

Comment: yes has was not working with arrays earlier I tried [...new Set(xyz)]

Answer (score 11):

This works well for me and work when deleting from an array of objects too:

```
var array = [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'bob', faveColor: 'blue' }, 
    { id: 2, name: 'jane', faveColor: 'red' }, 
    { id: 3, name: 'sam', faveColor: 'blue' }
];

// remove people that like blue

array.filter(x => x.faveColor === 'blue').forEach(x => array.splice(array.indexOf(x), 1));
```

There might be a shorter more effecient way to write this but this does work.

Answer (score 10):

It feels necessary to post an answer with `O(n)` time :). The problem with the splice solution is that due to the underlying implementation of array being [literally an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233814/are-javascript-arrays-actually-implemented-as-arrays), each `splice` call will take `O(n)` time. This is most pronounced when we setup an example to exploit this behavior:

```
var n = 100
var xs = []
for(var i=0; i<n;i++)
  xs.push(i)
var is = []
for(var i=n/2-1; i>=0;i--)
  is.push(i)
```

This removes elements starting from the middle to the start, hence each remove forces the js engine to copy `n/2` elements, we have `(n/2)^2` copy operations in total which is quadratic.

The splice solution (assuming `is` is already sorted in decreasing order to get rid of overheads) goes like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<is.length; i++)
  xs.splice(is[i], 1)
```

However, it is not hard to implement a linear time solution, by re-constructing the array from scratch, using a mask to see if we copy elements or not (sort will push this to `O(n)log(n)`). The following is such an implementation (not that `mask` is boolean inverted for speed):

```
var mask = new Array(xs.length)
for(var i=is.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
  mask[is[i]] = true
var offset = 0
for(var i=0; i<xs.length; i++){
  if(mask[i] === undefined){
    xs[offset] = xs[i]
    offset++
  }
}
xs.length = offset
```

I ran this on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/popmany) and for even `n=100` the splice method is a full 90% slower. For larger `n` this difference will be much greater.

Answer (score 9):

I find this the most elegant solution:

```
const oldArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const removeItems = [1, 3, 5]

const newArray = oldArray.filter((value) => {
    return !removeItems.includes(value)
})

console.log(newArray)
```

output:

```
[2, 4]
```

or even shorter:

```
const newArray = oldArray.filter(v => !removeItems.includes(v))
```

Comment: Thanks clean and simple!

Answer (score 7):

```
function filtermethod(element, index, array) {  
    return removeValFromIndex.find(index)
}  
var result = valuesArr.filter(filtermethod);
```

MDN reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @riship89 The fiddle is down

Comment: @Karna: fiddle is down

Comment: Please note that at the time of writing (june 2014), Array.prototype.find is part of the current ES6 draft and only implemented in current [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 6):

In pure JS you can loop through the array backwards, so `splice()` will not mess up indices of the elements next in the loop:

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ( yuck(arr[i]) ) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work yuck is not a function, so assumed it is the index of unwanted element indexes, & used yuck[arr[i]]

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution using ES5. This seems more appropriate for most applications nowadays, since many do no longer want to rely on jQuery etc.

When the indexes to be removed are sorted in ascending order:

```
var valuesArr = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"];   
var removeValFromIndex = [0, 2, 4]; // ascending

removeValFromIndex.reverse().forEach(function(index) {
  valuesArr.splice(index, 1);
});
```

When the indexes to be removed are not sorted:

```
var valuesArr = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"];   
var removeValFromIndex = [2, 4, 0];  // unsorted

removeValFromIndex.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; }).forEach(function(index) {
  valuesArr.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Quick ES6 one liner:

```
const valuesArr = new Array("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5");   
const removeValFromIndex = new Array(0,2,4);

const arrayWithValuesRemoved = valuesArr.filter((value, i) => removeValFromIndex.includes(i))
```

Comment: Your code should run faster if you make `removeValFromIndex` a `Set()` and use `removeValFromIndex.has` instead of `includes`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), you can use `_.filter()` to solve your problem.

```
var valuesArr = new Array("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5");
var removeValFromIndex = new Array(0,2,4);
var filteredArr = _.filter(valuesArr, function(item, index){
                  return !_.contains(removeValFromIndex, index);
                });
```

Additionally, if you are trying to remove items using a list of items instead of indexes, you can simply use `_.without()`, like so:

```
var valuesArr = new Array("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5");
var filteredArr = _.without(valuesArr, "V1", "V3");
```

Now `filteredArr` should be `["V2", "V4", "V5"]`

Comment: How contains is implemented in underscore... be careful if it's equivalent to indexOf inside of filter... not optimum at all...

Answer (score 1):

You can correct your code by replacing `removeValFromIndex` with `removeValFromIndex.reverse()`. If that array is not guaranteed to use ascending order, you can instead use `removeValFromIndex.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a })`.

Comment: Looks good to me - http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/gDcFu/2/. Although this makes the supposition that the removal list is in order.

Comment: @minopret: Thanks but it will only work if indexes in `removeValFromIndex` are in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
valuesArr = removeValFromIndex.reduceRight(function (arr, it) {
    arr.splice(it, 1);
    return arr;
}, valuesArr.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a }));
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gildean/ywULD/)

[MDN on Array.prototype.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)

Answer (score 1):

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (IE9+):

```
function removeMany(array, indexes) {
  return array.filter(function(_, idx) {
    return indexes.indexOf(idx) === -1;
  });
});
```

Or with ES6 [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (Edge+):

```
function removeMany(array, indexes = []) {
  return array.filter((_, idx) => indexes.indexOf(idx) === -1)
}
```

Comment: indexOf inside of filter... not optimum

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickie.

```
function removeFromArray(arr, toRemove){
    return arr.filter(item => toRemove.indexOf(item) === -1)
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const arr2 = removeFromArray(arr1, [2, 4, 6]) // [1,3,5,7]
```

Comment: indexOf inside of filter... not optimum

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var valuesArr = new Array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5");
console.info("Before valuesArr = " + valuesArr);
var removeValFromIndex = new Array(0, 2, 4);
valuesArr = valuesArr.filter((val, index) => {
  return !removeValFromIndex.includes(index);
})
console.info("After valuesArr = " + valuesArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) could be what you are looking for.
maybe something like this would work?

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(valuesArray, removeValFromIndexes );
```

Comment: But the `.splice()` method is not expecting a list of elements to remove, it is expecting a single index of the element at which to start removing followed by the number of elements to remove...

Answer (score 0):

```
var valuesArr = new Array("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5");   
var removeValFromIndex = new Array(0,2,4);

console.log(valuesArr)
let arr2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < valuesArr.length; i++){
  if (    //could also just imput this below instead of index value
    valuesArr[i] !== valuesArr[0] && // "v1" <--
    valuesArr[i] !== valuesArr[2] && // "v3" <--
    valuesArr[i] !== valuesArr[4]    // "v5" <--
  ){
    arr2.push(valuesArr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

This works. However, you would make a new array in the process. Not sure if thats would you want or not, but technically it would be an array containing only the values you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lodash js library functions (`_.forEach()`, `_.remove()`). I was using this technique to remove multiple rows from the table.

```js
let valuesArr = [
    {id: 1, name: "dog"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "cat"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "rat"}, 
    {id: 4, name: "bat"},
    {id: 5, name: "pig"},
]; 
let removeValFromIndex = [
    {id: 2, name: "cat"}, 
    {id: 5, name: "pig"},
]; 
_.forEach(removeValFromIndex, (indi) => {
    _.remove(valuesArr, (item) => {
        return item.id === indi.id;
    });
})
console.log(valuesArr)
/*[
    {id: 1, name: "dog"},  
    {id: 3, name: "rat"}, 
    {id: 4, name: "bat"},
];*/
```

Don't forget to clone (`_.clone(valuesArr)` or `[...valuesArr]`) before mutate your array

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a tweak to the answer by @nnnnnn, but I would also remove potential duplicate indices as this will otherwise cause additional rows to be deleted:

```
function arrayUnique(arr) {
    return arr.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
}

function arrayDeleteMulti(arr, idxSet) {

    idxSet = arrayUnique(idxSet).sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });
    
    for (var i = idxSet.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
        arr.splice(idxSet[i],1);

    return arr
}
```

So in this test

```
var arr = [`v0`, `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4`, `v5`];
console.log(arrayDeleteMulti(arr, [4,4,4,0,2]))
```

We do get

```
[ "v1", "v3", "v5" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a **reducer**, validate it by the index that returns the non-selected values and then order it.

```js
 var valuesArr = new Array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5");
  var r = new Array(0, 2, 4);

  const data = valuesArr
    .reduce((p, c, i) => (!r.includes(i) ? [...p, c] : p), [])
    .sort((a, b) => b - a);

  console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try and use `delete array[index]` This won't completely remove the element but rather sets the value to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks but I want to remove the elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
removeValFromIndex.forEach(function(toRemoveIndex){
    valuesArr.splice(toRemoveIndex,1);
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

#### For Multiple items or unique item:

I suggest you use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

## Don't ever use indexOf if you already know the index!:

```
var valuesArr = ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"];
var removeValFrom = [0, 2, 4];

valuesArr = valuesArr.filter(function(value, index) {
     return removeValFrom.indexOf(index) == -1;
}); // BIG O(N*m) where N is length of valuesArr and m is length removeValFrom
```

## Do:

with Hashes... using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
  var valuesArr = ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"];
  var removeValFrom = {};
  ([0, 2, 4]).map(x=>removeValFrom[x]=1); //bild the hash.
  valuesArr = valuesArr.filter(function(value, index) {
      return removeValFrom[index] == 1;
  }); // BIG O(N) where N is valuesArr;
```

Answer (score -2):

You could construct a `Set` from the array and then create an array from the set.

```js
const array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 1];
const uniqueArray = [...new Set(array)];
console.log(uniqueArray); // Result: [1, 2, 3, 5]
```