# Delete array element based on elements in an array as index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array as

```
let arr1 = [0,2] This is always sorted
```

Note: These elements in array represent indexes to be deleted from another array.

I have another array as:

```
let arrOvj = [1,4,6,7,21,17,12]
```

I want to delete element of arrObj,
based on indexes present in arr1.

So after deletion expected OP should be,

```
[4,7,21,17,12].
```

So how can I achieve this.

I tried as:

```
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
   arrObj.splice(arr1[i],1)
}
```

But this is giving incorrect result.

Example: If arr1=[0]

It deletes first two elements instead of deleting element at index 0 of arrObj.

What other alternative can I follow so it deletes from provided index value only

Please let me know if anyone need any further information.

Comment: Also, after deleting, the index will change, so you could run arr1 backwards

Comment: Sorry actually I tried with splice itself but mistakenly typed wrong over here

Comment: @ariel Sorry I didn't understand, could you please show it in code if possible or any article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove multiple elements from array in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425009/remove-multiple-elements-from-array-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop backwards over the indices to delete so that elements will never be shifted into a location that has not been already processed.

```js
let arr1 = [0,2] 
let arrOvj = [1,4,6,7,21,17,12]
for(let i = arr1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) arrOvj.splice(arr1[i], 1);
console.log(arrOvj);
```

Comment: @SushantRad Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Other way of doing it is using the filter method on the array and removing out the corresponding indexes as follows:

```js
let arrObj = [1,4,6,7,21,17,12]
let indexes = [0,2]

let newArr = arrObj.filter((ele, index) => !indexes.includes(index));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) here.

```js
let arr1 = [0, 2];
let arrOvj = [1, 4, 6, 7, 21, 17, 12];

arrOvj = arr1.reduceRight((a, c) => (a.splice(c, 1), a), arrOvj);

console.log(arrOvj);
```